# TestNG How do I run all dependent tests with testng.xml calling only one method

Tags: testng

I created lots of tests in .java file, defining complex dependencies. Now if I run any @test method in the class using IDEA Run Configuration, it runs all dependent test methods. But, If I call a method from tetsng.xml, it says that dependent methods are not included in the . 
Why do I need to redeclare all dependencies in .xml file again:

```html
<methods>
  <include name="createCabinetAndLogin" />
  <include name="loginAndFillAgreement" />
  <include name="loginCreateShopAndCheck" />
</methods>
```

If I want to run only one method and let testNG decide it's dependencies:

```html
<methods>
  <include name="loginCreateShopAndCheck" />
</methods>
```

Comment: still having this issue in 2020. TestNG is braindead, just use Spock instead.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if someone wants to run just one method and not the dependencies, then what should testng do?  Just happens that you want it the other way around :)

You are including specific methods in the xml which means that that is all you want to run.

The only thing that can help you here, I believe, is groups.
Put all dependent methods and the test you want in a group and run by group from the xml.

Ideally, I would create different classes for different functionality and not club all tests in one class.

Comment: No, it doesn't "just happen" to be the other way around. Running a test without the EXPLICITLY declared dependencies is a questionable use case. That's what 'dependency' means: this test doesn't work unless the other test is executed before'. Meanwhile executing only the necessary amount of code ie "just this test and everything required to make it work ie it's dependencies" is a thing nearly every developer needs every single day.